# How can I see which devices are synced with my Firefox?

Tags: firefox, sync

I have set up Firefox Sync on several devices. I can give a name to each device, but, I could find no way to see the list of devices which I already synced. How can I get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [recent post on the Mozilla support forums](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/986433) seems to suggest that this is not possible, but there is a workaround:

> Unfortunately, there is no "standard" method of doing this, more of a workaround. If you are syncing tabs, you can enter about:sync-tabs in the location bar or Firefox button --> history --> tabs from other devices. I just tested this with the new Firefox sync in Aurora and couldn't find a more practical method either.